# jQuery event to stop on mouseup

Tags: jquery, mousedown, mouseup

I am trying to make a very simple application where the user can draw into a table with a selected color when the mouse button is down, and the event stops when the mouse is up.

The drawing works well, the only problem is that the event doesn't stop when the mouse is released.
I've tried it in many ways, but obviously I am doing something wrong. Also tried to bind and unbind the event, but didn't work either.

You can see one version of the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mFzkG/8/

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is bind and unbind event from table cell.

```
 var currentColor;
    $('.colors').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.40);
        currentColor = $(this).css("background-color");
        $('.colors').not(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });


    $('table').mousedown(
    function() {
        $('td').bind('hover', function(){
            $(this).css(
            "background-color", currentColor
            );            
        });
        }).mouseup(function(){
            $('table td').unbind('hover');
            $('table').css(function(){
                return false;
        });
        });


    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $("td").css("background-color", "white")
    }
    );
```

And here is working jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mFzkG/12/

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it like this:

```javascript
    var currentColor;
    var isMouseDown = false;       
    $('.colors').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.40);
        currentColor = $(this).css("background-color");
        $('.colors').not(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });
    $('td').mousedown(function() {        
        isMouseDown = true;
    });
    $('td').mouseup(function() {
        isMouseDown = false;
    });
    $('td').hover(function() {
        if (isMouseDown) {
            $(this).css("background-color", currentColor);    
        }
    });
    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $("td").css("background-color", "white")
    });
```

So, I think the correct implementation would be to capture the `mouseup`/`mousedown` events, hold the state in a variable `isMouseDown` and check this variable in the `hover()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You might also try this jquery code :

```
$('table').mousedown(
function() {
    $('td').bind('mousedown mousemove', function(){
        $(this).css(
        "background-color", currentColor
        );            
    });
    });
$('table').mouseup(
    function() {
        $('td').unbind('mousedown mousemove');
    });
```