# Mousedown callback won't stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, mousedown

I am trying to track the mouse position while you are clicking and dragging inside a div, and only while you are clicking and dragging. I used

```
 $("div").mousedown(function() {
        $("div").mousemove(function(event) {
                $('div').html("( " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY + " )");
        });
    })
```

I have also tried

```
$("div").bind("mousedown mouseup", function () {
    $("div").mousemove(function (event) {
        $('div').html("( " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY + " )");
    });
});
```

but they both keep tracking the mouse's position even after I let go of the mouse. How can I stop it after I stop clicking?

It's worth noting I have seen the answer from [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802184/jquery-event-to-stop-on-mouseup), it won't work for me and I'm not sure why.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/7G7tx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
 $("div").mousedown(function() {
    $("div").on('mousemove', function(event) {
       $('div').html("( " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY + " )");
    });
 })

 $("div").mouseup(function() {
    $("div").off('mousemove');
 })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7G7tx/2/

You bind the event when the mouse button is pressed and unbind it when the button is released.

Comment: this will remove all mousemove handlers from target div, which might brake other functionality attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not cleaning your event handlers, and instead adding more and more.

Check this out

```
 $("div").mousedown(function() {
     var mouseMoveHandler = function (event) {
         $('div').html("( " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY + " )");
     };

     var mouseUpHandler = function (event) {
         $("div")
             .off('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
             .off('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
     };

     $("div")
         .on('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
         .on('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7G7tx/3/